# Prove $(xyz)^{2}(x^2+y^{2}+z^{2})≤(xy)^{2}+(yz)^{2}+(xz)^{2}$

Tags: inequality

> **Question:**  prove that if  $x,y,z\in \Bbb R$ and $x+y+z=3$ then $$(xyz)^{2}(x^2+y^{2}+z^{2})≤(xy)^{2}+(yz)^{2}+(xz)^{2}.$$

I don't have any ideas to prove that.

Comment: Start by homogenizing the inequality.

Answer (score 3):

This does not hold for $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3.$

Intuitively: the condition allows one to have the absolute value of each of the variables to be $\ge 1.$ Further, the objective only depends on this magnitude. But then the LHS is a eighth degree polynomial of the magnitudes, while the RHS is a fourth degree polynomial, so it is easy to violate the relation by picking large enough magnitude for $(x,y,z)$.

Concretely, for $(x,y,z) = (2,2,-1),$

$$\mathrm{LHS} = 16 \times( 4 + 4 + 1) = 16 \times 9 = 144, $$

$$\mathrm{RHS} = 4^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 = 24. $$

If instead you had the condition $|x| + |y| + |z| = 3,$ then approaches like the one suggested by Jack are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x,y,z>0$, you want to prove that $x+y+z=3$ implies
$$ x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2} $$
or that, in general,
$$ 81(x^2+y^2+z^2)\leq\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)(x+y+z)^4 $$
which is a consequence of the [generalized Holder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_H%C3%B6lder's_inequality).

Comment: How I can prove the last inequality ?

Comment: @KînanJœd: the linked Wikipedia page contains a proof, too.

Comment: I can't understand sir , how I take $p=?$ and $q=?$

Comment: How many factors do you see in the RHS of the last line?

Comment: Yes I see 3 , but 81 ??

Comment: @KînanJœd: see the comment about *Start by homogenizing the inequality*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95310/discussion-between-kinan-joed-and-jack-daurizio).

Answer (score 0):

For positive variables by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x^2y^2+x^2z^2)\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}2x^2yz=xyz\sum_{cyc}x=$$
$$=\frac{xyz}{243}\left(\sum_{cyc}x\right)^6=\frac{xyz}{243}\left(\sum_{cyc}(x^2+2xy)\right)^3\geq\frac{xyz}{243}\left(3\sqrt[3]{\sum_{cyc}x^2\left(\sum_{cyc}xy\right)^2}\right)^3=$$
$$=\frac{xyz\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}xy\right)^2}{9}\geq\frac{xyz\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2\cdot3\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2yz}{9}=x^2y^2z^2\sum_{cyc}x^2.$$